# Recurring URL when redirecting with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-302

I'm trying to add a rule into my .htaccess file so that if I am changing my website at all, it will redirect the user to an "under construction" page when they try to access my site.

I'm using:

```
# SITE UNDER CONSTRUCTION REDIRECT
Redirect 302 / http://redsquirrelsoftware.co.uk/construction.html
```

But this then sends me to http://redsquirrelsoftware.co.uk/construction.htmlconstruction.htmlconstruction.htmlconstruction.htmlconstruction.htmlconstruction.htmlconstruction.htmlconstruction.htmlconstruction.htmlconstruction.htmlconstruction.html and I obviously get a 404 error.

How do I stop the recursive tail on the web address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Redirect` is a `mod_alias` directive that can't be mixed with `mod_rewrite` directives, so to prevent the loop you should use only mod_rewrite directives like this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !construction\.html   [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !folder_to_exclude    [NC]
RewriteRule .*           /construction.html      [R=301,L]
```

This answer assumes `/construction.html` page is in the same domain. If it isn't, replace:

```
RewriteRule .*             /construction.html         [R=301,L]
```

with

```
RewriteRule .*   http://new_domain/construction.html  [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Works like a charm thanks! Two points, in the last line you have `[R=301,L]` - I'm guessing the 301 is the redirect code? In which case should that be changed to 302 as it is only a temporary redirect?

Comment: And secondly, how would I go about excluding just a single file from this redirect? For example if there's a T&C's page, could that be then excluded from the redirect?

Comment: Yes, there is no problem changing it to `R=302` or just `R`. I will update the answer with the exclusion.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a precondition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/construction.html
Redirect 302 / http://redsquirrelsoftware.co.uk/construction.html
```

Comment: I've tried adding that line in, and I get - 

You don't have permission to access /construction.htmlconstruction.htmlconstruction.htmlconstruction.htmlconstruction.htmlconstruction.htmlconstruction.htmlconstruction.htmlconstruction.htmlconstruction.htmlconstruction.htmlconstruction.htmlconstruction.htmlconstruction.htmlconstruction.htmlconstruction.html on this server.

Additionally, a 302 Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.